# How can I add all values from a tuple into a dictionary?

Tags: python, function, lambda

Say I have a list of three-tuples and I want a function to add them into a nested dictionary two layers deep for example:

```
lst = [('Watermelon', 200, (1,4)), ('Apple', 100, (2, 23)), ('Apple', 120, (1, 33))]
```

and I want to return a dictionary f that looks like:

```
f = {'Watermelon': {(1,4): 200}, 'Apple': {(2, 23): 100, (1, 33): 120 }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import collections as co

dd = co.defaultdict(dict)

for item in lst: 
    dd[item[0]].update({item[2]:item[1]})
```

Result:

```
In [31]: dd
Out[31]: 
defaultdict(dict,
            {'Watermelon': {(1, 4): 200},
             'Apple': {(2, 23): 100, (1, 33): 120}})
```

Comment: I'm finding hard to understand why the OP unmarked this as the correct answer.

Comment: @CONvid19: I believe because of the import and possibly lack of comfort with a defaultdict. I initially thought it too much, but I like this answer.

Comment: I liked and upvoted your answer because its from far the most clean.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that. I've seen your answers to other questions, and upvoted them too.

Comment: sorry that was by accident! your answer is great thanks

Answer (score 3):

This will work. No imports required <s>and is more readable than the comprehension-type syntax.</s>

```
dictionary = {}
for a, b, c in lst:
    if a not in dictionary:
        dictionary[a] = {}
    dictionary[a][c] = b
```

---

### EDIT

1. Agree with DavidBurke. Comprehensions are indeed intuitive and readable. They should not be taken too far, though. ;)

Feel free to make corrections. This answer has come to the top so it shouldn't be misleading.

Comment: Not to be one of the many hair-splitting pedants on SO, but I find the dictionary comprehension syntax to be very readable and intuitive... and shorter. I glance at a for loop and think it could be compiling data, or it could be executing functions. I have to mentally parse the code to find out.  +1 for working code, btw.

Comment: Instead of `if a not in dictionary.keys():` may be a simpler `if a not in dictionary:`

Answer (score 1):

Simplest syntax:

```
{a: {c: b} for a, b, c in lst}
```

This is a dictionary generation that outputs `a: {c: b}` for each item in list, unpacking them in sequential order as `a, b, c`.

*This doesn't get quite what you want, as you have common keys that you want turned into a list. Other answers do that, less elegant as they are and must be. I'm leaving this here to help any future Googler who doesn't have quite the same requirement you do.*

Comment: Doesn't output what the op wants: `{'Watermelon': {(1,4): 200}, 'Apple': {(2, 23): 100, (1, 33): 120 }}` , your answer output: `{'Watermelon': {(1, 4): 200}, 'Apple': {(1, 33): 120}}` -  https://trinket.io/python3/5c209fdc20

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict


keys = [name for name, *_ in lst]
vals = [pair for _, *pair in lst]

f = defaultdict(dict)

for key, val in zip(keys, vals):
    f[key].update({val[1]: val[0]})
```

Result:

> ```
> defaultdict(dict,
>             {'Watermelon': {(1, 4): 200},
>              'Apple': {(2, 23): 100, (1, 33): 120}})
> ```